# How to attach windows application to my c# app?

Tags: c#

I would like to attached windows application to my private application.
There is a windows based application that I would like to attached to my 
Window app. Let's say I have dialog app and i want to attached to the 0,0 location
Of my app?

Is there a way to do that ?
Thanks for the help!

P.S
I don't have the code for the desired window application.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand what you are trying to do here.  What do you mean by "attach" and what do you mean by "private."

Comment: I think he wants the two applications docked together.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Win32 API calls (so yeah, P/Invoke).  An example of this that comes to mind can be found in CodeProject.  The article I'm referring to uses MS-Word and attaches it into the custom application, so that it looks like one of the windows of the custom app.

Check the link out - hope it helps...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/winwordcontrol.aspx